# Create a calendar not accessible to other app on device in CalendarProvider

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, android-calendar

AFAIK CalendarProvider is a storage where any app can read/write/edit any calendar with READ/WRITE permissons.

I wanna create a calendar and save event, But I don't want any app on device be able to access calendar and events created by my app.

Is it possible with CalendarProvider? If possible, How?

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible. You cannot create calendar in `CalendarProvider` and guarantee that no app can delete or edit it.

However there is a column called [CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.CalendarColumns.html#CALENDAR_ACCESS_LEVEL) that you must set when creating a new calendar. You can set this column as [CAL_ACCESS_READ](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.CalendarColumns.html#CAL_ACCESS_READ) or [CAL_ACCESS_NONE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.CalendarColumns.html#CAL_ACCESS_NONE). This indicates that this calendar is read only.

Setting this column doesn't prevent other apps from deleting or updating the calendar or adding event to this. But I have tested this before and all official calendar apps consider this field and doesn't allow users to edit read only calendars or events in read only calendars. For example Birthday and Holiday calendars from gmail account both have `CAL_ACCESS_READ`. (You can query to see this).

Comment: Thanks Misagh! I believe the same too. But even then, I was trying to search if it could be possible.